# Automatically create .tikz file after compiling .tex file of external tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

I value the function of the `tikzscale`-package. A remaining issue is the neccesity of having to save an extra `.tikz`-file for every external tikz-picture nested in a `.tex`-file. So when wanting to make changes within the tikzpicture, one always has to make the change in the `.tex`-file and then manually override the `.tikz`-file. When only making the changes in the .tikz file, the parent `.tex`-file will not be updated. Does anyone has an idea to automate this process? For instance how to automatically store a `.tikz` file after every compilation of the parent `.tex`-file? Appritiate any help.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your setup. Do you have the code of the `tikzpicture`s in two separate files?

Comment: I am sorry, yes the `tikzscale`-package requires a `.tikz`-file. But the `.tikz`-file itself cannot be compiled individually. So to make a change one has to make the change in the `.tex`-file of the tikzpicture and then saving the `.tikz`-file. This `.tikz`-file is then used in a document as the tikzpicture and can be scaled with the benefits of the `tikzscale`-package (which I need).

Comment: So you have a `.tex` file just for the diagram(s)? You can do `\input{diagram.tikz}` in that file, there's no need to duplicate the diagram code.

Comment: Thats it! Perfect thanks!